# Cordova - all objects are moved to the left

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Good day,
My problem is cordova on android 4.4 and 4.3
It like as all Object shift to the left:

[image]

But on android 5.0 it like:

[image]

Code of page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/phonon.css" />
    <style>
        .uvitani {
            font-size: 250%;
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        }

        .tlacitko {
            margin: 0;
            color: #0084e7;
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function barva() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0065b3");
        }
    }
</script>

<body style="background-color: #0084e7;" onload="barva();">
    <center>
        <p class="uvitani">Vítejte v aplikaci ISAS&nbsp;do&nbsp;kapsy</p>
        <button class="btn tlacitko" onclick='document.location="styl.html";'>Pokračovat</button>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it to look at Android 4.4, as well as on Android 5.0 ( Statusbar smozřejmě into this error counting )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use webkit prefix, chrome 30 (that's the webview of android 4.4 phones) maybe doesn't support transform property :

```
.uvitani {
     font-size: 250%;
     margin: 0;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-right: -50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.tlacitko {
     margin: 0;
     color: #0084e7;
     background-color: white;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 50%;
     margin-right: -50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```